# placement of the participle phrase

Tags: meaning-in-context, participial-adjectives

> And the classy Oxford feeling of nothing mattering except books and poetry and Greek statues, and [nothing worth mentioning **having happened since the Goths sacked Rome.**] (Coming up for air)

The placement of the participle phrase confuses me, why is the participle phrase placed behind worth mentioning instead of being right behind the noun **nothing**?

> Nothing **having happened since the Goths sacked Rome** worth mentioning.

If the sentence above is correct,
can the sentence be understood as :

> Nothing which had happened since the Goths sacked Rome worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the phrase after *mentioning* or after *nothing*, they are entirely equivalent. They parse differently, but the end effect is the same. It is a matter of style or personal preference.

You are correct in your understanding, though you missed a word out of it:

> Nothing which had happened since the Goths sacked Rome **was** worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "nothing worth mentioning" is an idiom, and will normally be kept together.

> Did anything happen? / Nothing worth mentioning.

In the sentence from mthe question this phrase can be broken apart with little change in meaning, although a certian emphasis is lost, but such a form would be less likely.